# What is the ADL in iPOJO?

Tags: ipojo

I read in the iPOJO website.

"iPOJO also provides an architecture description language to design applications in a flexible and hierarchic manner"

What is the ADL in iPOJO ? we consider metadata.xml as an ADL ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

An ADL is an architecture description language. In iPOJO is has two format:

- an API (DSL)
- A XML-based description

Based on the DSL, it can support any other format.

Clement